# Git pull from my public repository not working

Tags: github, repository, git-pull

This is my `.git/config` configuration file in my repository:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:<username>/<repository>.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[user]
    name = <username>
```

I have correctly configured my public ssh key in github. I pushed my changes into this repository from another machine, which where correctly updated into github.

However in my current machine, when I make a git pull request:

```
git pull origin master
```

It says "already up to date"

When it's not the case at all, the updated files in my github repository are not in my local repository.

What can I be doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried the following from the answer from Olivier Refalo:

In github and in local the branches are master.

The output to the command:

```
git for-each-ref --format="local: %(refname:short) <--sync--> remote: %(upstream:short)" refs/heads
```

Is the following:

> local: master <--sync--> remote:

`git remove -v` returns the following output:

> origin    git@github.com:username/repository.git (fetch)
>
> origin    git@github.com:username/repository.git (push)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find out what was the problem so what I did was a new git clone from github in order to get the updated files.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple things can happen here:

I would trust git, the remote is in sync with your local. The problem here is that it may be pointed to a different location than want you think.

1. you may be pushing local branch XYZ (not master) to origin/master
2. you may be pushing to a different URL

to figure this out, run the following code:

1. git branch, make sure you are on master
2. git for-each-ref --format="local: %(refname:short) <--sync--> remote: %(upstream:short)" refs/heads
3. git remote -v

The later will show an association table showing which local branch syncs with which remote.
Finally the latest statement shows your remote urls.

I took these commands from a project of mine [G2](https://github.com/orefalo/g2)

Answer (score -1):

try ot use force pull. add "force" between git and pull