# Git pull not pulling the latest revision

Tags: git, github

We use Github for source control in our organization. Multiple developers continuously merge their changes to remote source repository. In my case I cloned the repository when two weeks back and there were multiple merges after that. Now I am trying to get the latest revision of the code using.

```
git pull origin master
```

I for sure know that there were multiple merges that have gone in since last time I cloned but pull command tells me that its already up to date. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Is `git fetch` showing anything?

Comment: @Nic It didn't give me anything .. it just asked for credentials

Comment: try a git reset --hard origin master , may be your local head is not on the good index

Answer (score 20):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~20 # some large number
git pull origin master
```

This fixed my problem with an un-pullable update. The idea is to push HEAD back far enough to clear up any confusion for git. Then make the desired pull.

Comment: How about resolving this?

Answer (score 6):

For me the solution was:

from the current branch I executed  `git pull origin ${current-branch-name}` in my specific case the complete command was:

From `develop` branch:  `git pull origin develop`

The `git reset --hard HEAD` and `git pull origin HEAD` commands do not work for me.

Comment: This solved the issue for me where the reset did not. Thanks for that.

Comment: This worked for me! I was having issues in one of my branches where I cannot pull the latest commit. I switched to a different branch and pulled using the suggested code above and it worked!

Comment: This worked for me whereas the other suggestions did not. Wondering what might have caused this scenario, as this kept happening lately. I suspect it has to do with what other people are doing at the repository (minimal experience and communication)

Answer (score 3):

One explanation would be that the latest commits have been done on another branch, as explained in "[Git pull from my public repository not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086897/git-pull-from-my-public-repository-not-working)".

The other possibility is for you to be in a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714) mode.
That would make any `git pull` "up-to-date" since you are in any branch.

Answer (score 1):

I used Team Explorer from my Visual Studio application and was able to Sync, Fetch, and Pull. That finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

For me, nothing seemed to work and I had to clone the repository from GitHub again. As a last resort that might be an option.

Comment: If all other things fail, you can avoid needing to clone the entire repo by going to a different branch, deleting the problematic one, running `git fetch` and then changing back to it.